# cloudfront CORS issue and cache invalidation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elastic-transcoder

We are using AWS transcoding to transcode our video files and cloudfront for content delivery. The problem we are facing is, after 2 or 3 days of file upload (it is uploaded in S3 and then transcoded by AWS Elastic Transcoder) cloudfront starts giving CORS issue on some files. Then we have to invalidate cache and it starts working fine. Any help on that why is that happening?